# How can I comment out multiple lines in jupyter notebook on a mac german keyboard?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard, comments

On juypter notebook somehow it does not work for me to comment out multiple lines with "cmd+shit+7" like it does on VS code for example...

Important to remember that I am on a GERMAN mac keyboard, so the "/" symbol can only be given by the "shift+7" combination (as far as I know)...

I am looking for something faster rather than holding "cmd" to then click at the beginning of every line and finally type "#" (which is anyway not much faster than typing # at the beginning of every line).

Anyone knows?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!